# ajax skips response from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass PHP echo values through AJAX, but on success function AJAX skips the if and else conditions and executes the else statements even when the if condition is met.

Below is my php and ajax code

**process_postadd.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-postAdd'])){
$istate = strip_tags($_POST['txt_istate']);
$iname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_iname']);   
if(empty($iname)){
    echo '1'; //check if iten name is empty
}
else{
try
    {   
        if($insertItem = $postItem->postAdd($istate,$iname)){
            echo "ok"; //sucessfully inserted
        }           
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }   
}   
}
```

**script.js**

```js
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
 /* validation */
 $("#postAddForm").validate({
  rules:
  {
        txt_istate: {
        required: true
        },
        txt_iname: {
            required: true
        },
   },
   messages:
   {

        txt_istate: {
        required: "state required"
        },
        txt_iname: {
            required:  "item name required"
        },
   },
   submitHandler: submitForm    
   });  
   /* validation */

   /* postadd submit */
     function submitForm()
   {        
        var data = $("#postAddForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'process_postadd.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function()
        {   
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; posting ...');
        },
        success :  function(response)
           {                        
                if(response == "ok"){

                    $("#btn-postAdd").html('<img src="btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Submiting item ...');
                    setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
                }
                else if(response == "1"){
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry, add item name</div>');
                        $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; SIGN U');
                        });

                }
                else{

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
                                        $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Submit Item');
                                });
                }
          }
        });
            return false;
    }
   /* postadd submit */
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="error">
                        <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
                        </div>
                            <form method= "POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postAddForm">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Item condition</label>

                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-00">
                                                <input name="txt_istate" id="radios-00" value="New"
                                                       type="radio">
                                                New</label>
                                            <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-11">
                                                <input name="txt_istate" id="radios-11" value="Used" 
                                                        type="radio">
                                                Used </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Adtitle">Item Name</label>

                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="Adtitle" name="txt_iname" placeholder="name of item"
                                                   class="form-control input-md" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

                                        <button class="btn btn-success" name="btn-postAdd" id="btn-postAdd" type="submit">
                                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Submit Item 
                                           </button>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: How about looking in the console, console.log the response to see if it is indeed "ok" or "1"  - also try calling the PHP from the command line with PHP error checking enabled and GET  substituted for POST

Comment: with PHP error checking enabled no error is displayed

Comment: Please share complete ajax request to help more... and what datatype u set for ajax request.

Possible case looks that the response is coming in different format what ajax in expecting.

Comment: have you missed this '}' out from your php?

Comment: the problem actually is when the PHP script echo "ok" or "1" the ajax response skips the condition for the if and else if and execute the else condition

Comment: If i get stuck on a return like this i normally place multiple echos in after if statement etc to see were i got to, can save having to look through =]  Just thought this may help you in the future

Comment: `console.log(response);` check if you don't have any errors

Comment: Hi, parsing pure echo from PHP is not the best idea as there may be pther symbols that you would not see on the page (things like body tags). To checkexactly how your responce looks like do console.log(respone); just before if. Have a look in the console what that string looks like. My guess would be that you are getting more things in response than you expect. Better approach would be to return a json encoded result, that way it is parse and your values are clean.

Comment: @Optimistic why do you think there's a need to check again in your php if the values are not empty while you did with the validate?

Comment: @Masivuye after doing echo json_encode("ok") and var res = console.log(response);      
 alert(res);  i get  response as undefined

Comment: @Masivuye i stand to be corrected, i read somewhere that that is the best practice should in case the user disables JAVASCRIPT or the browser is not supported

Comment: alright but then this script would be useless, if js is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try json_encode with your echo and add a console.log(response) for check the return

```
   if($insertItem = $postItem->postAdd($istate,$iname)){
        echo json_encode("ok"); //sucessfully inserted
    }
```

and

```
   if(empty($iname)){
        echo json_encode('1'); //check if iten name is empty
   }
```

Comment: it actually echos either "ok" or "1" through the else condition

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I don't think in your php you actually need to check if the name is not empty, you already did that using `jquery.validate();'

On your success delete this

```
else if(response == "1"){
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry, add item name</div>');
                        $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; SIGN U');
                        });

                }
```

and also on your php remove this

```
if(empty($iname)){
    echo '1'; //check if iten name is empty
}
```

That have been already taken care by your rules in `validate()`

Then your code will look like :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin_assets/js/validation.min.js"></script>// ignore this was for my test
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('document').ready(function()
{ 
 /* validation */
 $("#postAddForm").validate({
  rules:
  {
        txt_istate: {
        required: true
        },
        txt_iname: {
            required: true
        },
   },
   messages:
   {

        txt_istate: {
        required: "state required"
        },
        txt_iname: {
            required:  "item name required"
        },
   },
   submitHandler: submitForm    
   });  
   /* validation */

   /* postadd submit */
     function submitForm()
   {        
        var data = $("#postAddForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'process_postadd.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function()
        {   
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; posting ...');
        },
        success :  function(response)
           {                        
                if(response == "ok"){

                    $("#btn-postAdd").html('<img src="btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Submiting item ...');
                    setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
                }
                else{

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
                                        $("#btn-postAdd").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Submit Item');
                                });
                }
          }
        });
            return false;
    }
   /* postadd submit */
});
</script>


<div id="error"></div>

<form method="POST" id="postAddForm" action="">
  <input type="text" name="txt_istate" id="txt_istate">
  <input type="text" name="txt_iname" id="txt_iname">
  <button type="submit" name="btn-postAdd" id="btn-postAdd">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Ignore my form it was for testing purposes on my side. You have your form already**

**then your php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btn-postAdd'])) {

    $istate = strip_tags($_POST['txt_istate']);
    $iname  = strip_tags($_POST['txt_iname']);

    try {
        if ($insertItem = $postItem->postAdd($istate, $iname)) {
            echo "ok"; //sucessfully inserted
        } else {

            echo "could not add item";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

You good to go now.

Also take into consideration the comment from Auris.

Comment: @Masivuyeit still sends the "ok" through the error id

Comment: can you post the form as well @Optimistic

Comment: please what do you suggest I do